# Java8 Lambda expression to iterate over enum values and initialize final member

Tags: java, lambda, enums, java-8

I have a static enum like this:

```
private static enum standardAttributes {
    id, gender, firstname, lastname, mail, mobile
}
```

I need all the values as String. Therefore I have a method like this:

```
public static List<String> getStandardRecipientsAttributes() {
    List<String> standardAttributesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (standardAttributes s : standardAttributes.values())
        standardAttributesList.add(s.toString());

    return standardAttributesList;
}
```

There is no need to create the same List everytime this method is called. So I created a static member:

```
static final List<String> standardAttributesList;
static {
    standardAttributesList = getStandardRecipientsAttributes();
}
```

This is all fine, but I wonder if there is a fancy Lambda expression to replace the method. Something like this:

```
Arrays.asList(standardAttributes.values()).forEach((attribute) -> standardAttributesList.add(attribute.toString()));
```

Two questions:

1. Can I avoid the Arrays.asList wrapper?
2. How can I handle the compiler error: *The blank final field standardAttributesList may not have been initialized*?

Comment: Just wondering: wouldnt it make sense to have a member function in your enum that does this for you? If the only reason to have this enum is to collect a list of potential enum values and build a string representation of that - why do you externalize the second part?

Comment: Good point. I guess I put the blame on old legacy code and the missing will to refactor things :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do

```
static final List<String> standardAttributesList = 
                                           Stream.of(values())
                                                 .map(Enum::name)
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will create a Stream from an the array of values, apply the `.name()` method to each one and finally collect all the results into a List.

Comment: Perfect! I just want to add that the toList() method is from the Collectors class.

Comment: A nice article showing ways to iterate over Enum values in Java: http://www.baeldung.com/java-enum-iteration